# Congratulations, joriki!

Tags: discussion, reputation, specific-user, celebration

Congratulation to [joriki](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6622/joriki) for getting $100,001>100,000$ reputation!

Thanks for you amazing answers! You've helped a countless number of people in the M.SE community.

I will wish you, on the behalf of all the M.SE users, a big
$$\Large{\text{Congratulations, @joriki!}}\\
\large{\text{Thanks for all your contributions!}}\\
\text{- the M.SE Community}$$

Comment: I'm a huge Joriki fan. He's a top notch contributor. Bravo.

Comment: Well done, Joriki!

Comment: Joriki, thank you for all your wonderful contributions! I note that we both crossed at [100001](http://i.stack.imgur.com/70elP.png) :-)

Comment: I always thought @JyrkiLahtonen and joriki were the same person, for some reason. Now I don't even know who's the one I've been learning  from. Maybe both

Comment: LOL, @GitGud. IIRC someone else (jokingly) made the same suggestion once. May be I should upload a photo of myself to be used as an avatar to remove any doubt :-)

Comment: Congrats indeed :)

Comment: [A link explaining the meaning of *joriki*.](http://the-wanderling.com/joriki.html)

Comment: You answered the first question I asked. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you, @Jyrki. It is good to know that "the power of Joriki can be endlessly enlarged through regular practice."

Comment: Thank you to all people like Joriki who make this place great, here's to a long life for MSE.

Comment: @Sanath Would you *please* stop bumping these threads with trivial edits.

Comment: Please don't continue bumping the thread - there's no particular reason to remove the @-symbol, nor make trivial edits.

Comment: @Sanath you continue to post congratulatory questions and answers and bump them with trivial edits. This spams the home page. Please stop.

Comment: @BillDubuque etc: please have some understanding, he is only 14 years old.

Comment: @user 10293: I don't believe in the least that user "Sanath Devalapurkar" is 14 years old or if he is, that he wrote his posts without help. A teenager of that age understanding vector bundles on topoi and topological quantum field theory would have attained a level that Serre, Grothendieck, Tao and Deligne put together had not reached at that age. If that were so the net would have had thousands of entries on him (journalists love child prodigies) but there are essentially none, apart from the information on stack exchange sites (or nlab) which he put there himself.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: But Grothendieck didn't have internet. [This 14yo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suvjYM8Ruao#t=10m0s) Indian moderates PhysicsOverflow and [answers](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99643/why-does-bosonic-string-theory-require-26-spacetime-dimensions/140354#140354) on strings on MathOverflow. In 2013 I learned one-two things about Homotopy type theory and the guy doing the teaching is a 17yo school boy from some village in Italy, nowhere near a university. He didn't know what the order of a differential equation is but boy did he know his n-categories and Mahlo cardinals.

Comment: @NikolajK: I do have internet. he only claims to be 14 year old.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: In my opinion, we shouldn't really care whether someone claims to be 3 or 203. In fact, I don't think we should care about anything people put in their profiles, as long as it's not offensive and they are not clearly impersonating someone (like linking their personal website, for instance). That said, whether someone claims (or is) 3, 14 od 203, it doesn't mean we should just overlook it if he's repeatedly breaking rules (written or otherwise). I don't mean to suggest some extreme chastising in this case, but there's nothing wrong with pointing that out.

Comment: @AlexanderGrothendieck: Hahaha

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg There is now [this little entry](http://www.ams.org/meetings/sectional/2214_program_saturday.html#2214:AMSCP1) with "Sanath K Devalapurkar, West High School".

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Despite the fact that the user has deleted his account, since you've essentially accused someone else of lying and since your claim is demonstrably false, you should delete that comment.